# Dynamic date range query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates

I'm trying to create two cells that will update my query: A >= date"A1" and A <= date "B1".

My goal is to create a search page for the data, where the end user could insert a date or the `=today()` function and it would update the query. I am currently getting a formula parse error from:

```
=QUERY(Data!6:1397,"SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L WHERE A >= date"A1"and
 A <= date"B1"")
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
=Query(Data!A6:L1397,"Select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L where A>=date
 '"&TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and A <= date '"&TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

Note Column references for the source data set and that the likes of `date '"&TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'` are to accommodate the possible use of `=today()`.

May be worth mention that the above would be shorter as:

```
=Query(Data!A6:L1397,"Select * where A>=date '"&TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and 
A <= date '"&TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

Comment: can you explain a bit this part: '"&TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'  . What are the & for? and the TEXT?

Comment: thanks, and why doesn't work If I just write: where A>=date 'A1' and A <= date 'B1'") . assuming that the user will always enter dates in A1 and B1