# Evaluate date inside a query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am attempting to perform a query in Google Sheets, and one of the things I need to match is a date.  I have seen [other posts on this topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/74117/dynamic-date-range-query), but I am not having success.  The advice that isn't working for me involves this phrase: `(Col4=date '"&TEXT(A14,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'`

Here is the whole formula:

```
ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE(
"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wyewpz0j_IiKK8ESOapX5L4AedjvHccLZOOKS2tZGUA/",
"UsuallyAnotherSpreadsheetFile!B2:K")),"Select Col4, sum(Col8), sum(Col9) where  
(Col4=date '"&TEXT(A14,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND (Col3='" & $F$1 & "')  AND (Col1 = '" & 
ClientInfo!$H$1 & "') group by Col4")
```

I get the error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:

> PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "group" at line 1, column 124. Was expecting one of: "and" ... "or" ... ")" ...

I will [share my sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wyewpz0j_IiKK8ESOapX5L4AedjvHccLZOOKS2tZGUA/).  Please see if you are able to get it to match the date based on what is in A14 on the sheet called `Paste`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is due to a missing closing parenthesis before the first AND.

Once solving this, you will get as result the following

```
            sum     sum 
10/12/2016  296.1   2.5
```

To avoid the headers, before the last `"` add

```
 label sum(Col8) '', sum(Col9) ''
```

the final formula is

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE(
"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wyewpz0j_IiKK8ESOapX5L4AedjvHccLZOOKS2tZGUA/",
"UsuallyAnotherSpreadsheetFile!B2:K")),"Select Col4, sum(Col8), sum(Col9) where  
(Col4=date '"&TEXT(A14,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"') AND (Col3='" & $F$1 & "')  AND 
(Col1 = '" & ClientInfo!$H$1 & "') group by Col4 label sum(Col8) '', sum(Col9) ''")
```