# Using date as filter for my query formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I was having problem with my query formula. it does not filter the range of my values which depends on the date ranges that I have put up.

Here is my formula:

```
=query(all!B2:G, "select B,C,D,G where date '"&text(all!B2:B, "mm-dd-
yyyy")&"' >= date '"&text(E2, "mm-dd-yyyy")&"' and date '"&text(all!B2:B, 
"mm-dd-yyyy")&"' <= date '"&text(E3, "mm-dd-yyyy")&"' order by B DESC  label 
B'Date of Purchase', C 'OR Number', D 'Particulars', G 'Total Expenses' ")
```

Comment: I fear the formatting made the formula even harder to read.  Indenting 4 spaces makes it into a code block, so if you wanted to polish it a bit, please be my guest.

Answer (score 0):

The date format should be yyyy-mm-dd instead of mm-dd-yyyy

Reference:

- [Google Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

Related questions

- [Dynamic date range query](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74117/88163)